# How Android compiler understands underlying different processors instruction sets while creating binary?

Tags: compiler-construction

When we compile android app we don't need to think about what processor type it is using. e.g. if app is image processing related, app developer doesn't need to know which image processor DSP phone hardware has. Also each phone will have different vendor DSPs which will have different instruction sets. How compiler knows this?

Comment: It doesn't. It produces interpretive bytecode. And it is the runtime library that adapts to the display hardware, not the compiler.

Comment: It's Android, BTW :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Makes no difference. Just different byte code. It's still byte code, not native code.

Comment: @EJP: I know, I was just pointing out a typo to the OP :)